# Help in identifying crusty formation on Eucalyptus leaves

Tags: botany, mycology, pest-control

I am working with the plant species Eucalyptus perriniana (spinning gum) for one of my research projects. A few days into the experiment, I noticed some crusty deposits forming on several leaves (as shown in the attached photographs). I was wondering if anyone here might be able to identify it. I am not sure if the deposits are biological in nature, or if they are some kind of chemical precipitate.[image: Crusty formation on eucalyptus leaf]

[image: Crusty formation on eucalyptus leaf]